# What is the difference between ":i" and ":a" in avrdude command?

Tags: avrdude, command-line

What is the difference between `:i` and `:a` after my hex file path in avrdude command.

```
avrdude -C C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -V -pm32u4 -c avr109 -P COM8 -b 57600 -D -U flash:w:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-35CC2EF472BAA882EB5508D7552111AD/blink_RX_Led_ProMicro.ino.hex:i
```

and

```
avrdude -C C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -V -pm32u4 -c avr109 -P COM15 -b 57600 -D -U flash:w:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-35CC2EF472BAA882EB5508D7552111AD/blink_RX_Led_ProMicro.ino.hex:a
```

Comment: :-( The art of reading manuals is being lost more and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Avrdude file format specifiers.

```
avrdude -C C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -V -pm32u4 -c avr109 -P COM15 -b 57600 -D -U flash:w:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-35CC2EF472BAA882EB5508D7552111AD/blink_RX_Led_ProMicro.ino.hex:a
```

The final `:a` in this case is a format specifier meaning "auto detect; valid for input only, and only if the input is not provided at stdin."

An `:i` in the same position means "Intel Hex"

A complete list can be found here: https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_3.html#Option-Descriptions

Comment: It is worth noting that `:a` is the default, and can thus be omitted. Also, if this version of avrdude is not too old, it can understand the ELF file: no need to convert it to hex.